# How do I click a javascript "link"? Is it my xpath or my relenium/selenium usage?

Tags: r, selenium, xpath

Like the beginning to any problem before I post it on stack overflow I think I have tried everything.  This is a learning experience for me on how to work with javascript and xml so I'm guessing my problem is there.

My question is how to get the results of clicking on the parcel number links that are javascript links? I've tried getting the xpath of the link and using the $click method which following my intuition but this wasn't right or is at least not working for me.

Firefox 26.0
R 3.0.2

```
require(relenium)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
initializing_parcel_number <- "00000000000"
firefox <- firefoxClass$new()
firefox$get("http://www.muni.org/pw/public.html")
inputElement <- firefox$findElementByXPath("/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/input[1]")
inputElement$sendKeys(initializing_parcel_number)
inputElement$sendKeys(key = "ENTER")

##xpath to the first link. Or is it?
first_link <- "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[5]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"

##How I'm trying to click the thing. 
linkElement <- firefox$findElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[5]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")
linkElement$click()
```

Comment: Without the HTML, there can be no answers.

Comment: sounds poetic.  Should I provide you with the html of the url I've connected to in the code so far?

Comment: You should post the HTML, ideally just a relevantly-wide snippet, as part of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using `RSelenium`. See http://johndharrison.github.io/RSelenium/ . DISCLAIMER I am the author of the RSelenium package. A basic vignette on operation can be viewed at [RSelenium basics](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843) and 
[RSelenium: Testing Shiny apps](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/13408)

If you are unsure of what element is selected you can use the `highlightElement` utility method in the `webElement` class see the commented out code.
The element click event wont work in this case. You need to simulate a click using javascript:

```
require(RSelenium)
# RSelenium::startServer # if needed
initializing_parcel_number <- "00000000000"
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.muni.org/pw/public.html")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", "PAR1")
# webElem$highlightElement() # to visually check what elemnet is selected
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(initializing_parcel_number, key = "enter"))
# get first link containing javascript:getParcel
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '[href*="javascript:getParcel"]')
# webElem$highlightElement() # to visually check what elemnet is selected
# send a webElement as an argument. 
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].click();", list(webElem))

#
```

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting to RPubs for your documents but not for others.

Comment: That indicates a selenium server isnt running. If you have installed the package the vignettes should be in the package in the /docs directory also. The selenium server is explained in the RSelenium Basics vignette.

Comment: Wow. This is freaking awesome.  Have you done any promotion? Am I the last person in the world to hear of this package. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @cylondude. There is another vignette link here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ZCDx9UKox2g which discusses connecting with other browsers. Problems with Rpubs probably related to the vignettes calling <script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script> to make themselves look more presentable lol